# How are the Prophets connected to the Orbs?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

## The Orbs and The Prophets

### Events in the Show

> During the majority of Sisko's visions from the Prophets, we see him surrounded by beings resembling people he
>  has encountered in his life. Often there are more than half a dozen of these entities
>  present during the encounters. Incidentally, there are said to be ten
>  Orbs.
>  
>  After a Pah-Wraith possessed Dukat transports into the Bajoran shrine
>  onboard DS9, murdering Jadzia in his mission to attack the Orb and seal the wormhole,
>  only **one** prophet ever appears to Sisko in his visions again...
>  After, the Orb of the Emissary is found.
>  
>  We're also told that following Dukat's actions, communication with the
>  prophets is made impossible, and **all** the Orbs 'go dark'. I
>  don't recall mention in subsequent episodes of the Orbs returning to
>  normal after the Pah-Wraith is cast out of the wormhole, but this is implied; we do see Kai
>  Winn interact with one later on (though it fails to provide her with a
>  vision).

### Physical and Metaphysical bridge

These observations suggest a direct connection between the Orbs and the wormhole aliens.

Much as the wormhole is both a spatial phenomena; a space-time bridge between far flung points in the galaxy, and the container of a non-linear space-time environment necessary it's extra-dimensional inhabitants to exist, perhaps the hourglass shaped Orbs are also more than they seem.

They resemble a crystalline frozen hourglass, another metaphor for the nature of their mysterious heralds. Their distinctive dual funnel shape also recalls the twin apertures of the wormhole, as though the vector graphic images had leapt from the computer console into reality.

### Orbs ≈ Prophets

Perhaps they are a microcosm of the wormhole; mobile, encapsulated nexus points between the physical and meta-physical, where the rules of space and time cease to function as we understand them. They may serve as an extension of the will and influence of the prophets, akin to the probes sent out by federation vessels.

But could the Orbs be physical manifestations of the Prophets themselves? Multi-dimensional beings intersecting with normal space-time? Without the Orbs is there no way for the prophets to communicate with corporeal beings outside of the wormhole?

The prophets seem to be separate entities who appear to us as multi-faceted reflections of ourselves, not unlike a physical description of the Orbs. Are they separate from the prophets at all?

The Orbs were also sent to Bajor, and the Prophets often state that "We are of Bajor"; another strange connection between these metaphysical beings and the physical universe. They were found as far back as 30,000 years ago, shaping the fates of countless lives in the process.

### Canonical Answers

#### Contact with Other Lifeforms

In the pilot episode "Emissary", the Orbs are *almost* spoken of by the prophets:

> SISKO
> I'm not your enemy... I've been sent here by the people you
> contacted.
>
> PICARD ALIEN
> Contacted?
>
> SISKO
> With your devices. Your orbs...
>
> PICARD ALIEN
> We seek contact with other lifeforms... not corporeal
> creatures who would annihilate us...

This tacit acknowledgment of the Orbs purpose as a means to contact insinuates that they are indeed devices as Sisko describes them, though this is speculative.

The episode also features an Orb acting much more like an alien machine: It scans Sisko and Jadzia (and Dax) before absorbing Jadzia, leaving the wormhole and depositing her back on DS9.

#### Energy Form

Several times in the series we also see the prophets or their essence emerge from objects, manifest as blue energy (or red for the Pah Wraiths). If *this* is the "true" form of the prophets, it would add more credence to the Orbs as devices concept, and less to this notion of them as multi-dimensional intersections into our reality.

Never do we see an Orb physically destroyed, nor do we see the potential signature blue energy motif of a prophet concealed within, though they are possessed of some dazzling inner light source.

#### Metaphysical Hallucinations

The Orbs are named by the Bajorans after the nature of the visions they impart, names such as time, prophecy, contemplation, etc..

These distinctions strengthen a connection to the prophets as markers of the unique personality traits of individual beings.

### Conclusion

I suspect these questions are left unanswered deliberately to leave us uncertain as to where the meeting place between faith and science exists, leaving the audience with irreconcilable unknowns.

Is any of this ever made clear canonically?

Comment: The orbs appear to be aspects of the wormhole aliens (time, prophecy, contemplation, etc).

Comment: How are the Prophets connected to the Orbs? *Very carefully.*

Comment: @Valorum: Did it really become clear that this wasn't just what Bajoran clerics called them? The only really strong association with such an aspect I can remember was the orb of time (with "time" being an aspect of the wormhole aliens exactly how, given that they seemed to struggle with understanding the very concept in "Emissary"?), which was indeed used for a time travel. But the way the orbs were depicted, I wouldn't rule out other orbs could somehow be used for the same purpose.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - The orbs appear to have specific powers and specific ranges of interest

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I never considered that about the 'Time' Orb... doesn't really make sense when the Prophets are unfamiliar with the concept. Having said that, if they truly live outside of time, it would mean that knowledge the Prophets gained in the future would also be known to them in the past. So they have always known about time, just as they have never known about it... Unless it doesn't work that way! I'm still not clear on their relationship with the unfurling events in the corporeal universe.

Comment: @HotSauceCoconuts "they have always known about time, just as they have never known about it... Unless it doesn't work that way" - sounds like the DS9 writers were taking a continuity clue from the Doctor Who writers...

Comment: @FreeMan yeah... writers should stay away from time travel!

Comment: The orbs are phones but you can only call the Phophets

Comment: Definitely they are connected wirelessly, as I have not seen any wires...

Comment: I believe in the DS9 pilot, the Prophet(s) state that they were sent out as probes to search for intelligent life. Also, when Jadzia was sent back by them, she appeared as an orb, suggesting that the orbs represent their appearance.

Comment: or that perhaps... the orbs are merely how these beings appear when they intersect with normal spacetime, like how we would perceive a 4-dimensional object, only more complex. The fact that Jadzia was an orb when she emerged from their realm, or was otherwise transported via an orb rings true to this hypothesis.

Comment: @AaronGullison: "their appearance" - whose? The prophets'? Actually, if the orbs were said to have been sent out as "probes", I would take that as a hint that the orbs themselves are *not* the prophets, or their immediate manifestations in our universe, but rather some kind of "technology" created by the prophets.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper Yes, that's right. Most races constructs show anthropomorphism, so it would follow that the same logic applies here. It could also be that they've mastered colocation, being present in their constructs and in the wormhole at the same time.

Comment: @AaronGullison: I don't quite understand. It would be rather absurd to claim that, say, Sojourner or Curiosity look anything like humans.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper Construct, in this case, also applies to robotic probes as well as robots, which are usually seen as humanoid. Since the Orbs are the only artefact attributed to the  Prophets (outside the wormhole) it could be that they are the same or that they are similar in shape.

Comment: @AaronGullison: I'm sorry, I do not know what you're trying to say. The claim that constructs will necessarily look similar to their creators strikes me as quite nonsensical, as I have demonstrated by pointing out the real-life examples of Mars rovers. Consequently, the assumption that the Orbs on DS9 would necessarily resemble the "prophets" in any way seems completely baseless, unless there is any other supporting evidence.

Comment: The Mars rover doesn't bear much resemblance to a human being, but it does have cameras and sensors mounted on its 'head' and has 'arms' for collecting samples, which certainly isn't a far removed.

Comment: @HotSauceCoconuts: Cameras are mounted in an elevated location because you can see more on pictures taken like that. And that's already where parallels with a human head stop - for instance, Perseverance's "head" neither serves for energy intake, nor does it contain the rover's CPU, nor is it the only place where the rover has cameras, etc. If anything, this is an example of how humans try to see something human in many things, even though those things actually bear virtually zero resemblance to humans.

Comment: I guess you could argue it is closer to an insect! But even that is a comparison to a terrestrial life form, perhaps some distant genetic cousin of man.

Comment: I always took the "We are of Bajor" line to mean that they evolved on Bajor long ago, and eventually reached a point where they moved off into higher dimensions in the wormhole they built for that purpose. But there are a lot of ways to interpret, such as perhaps Bajor anchors the wormhole gravitationally somehow. But none of this was ever explained in-show, and the books aren't considered canon (not that I  came across an answer in the books either).  All we can do is guess.